# BLE HM-10 AT Commands through Bluetooth

Tags: bluetooth-low-energy, hm-10

I can configure the HM-10 through the serial port, set the baud rate, etc but I need to change these parameters via Bluetooth.
It is written in datasheet:

> AT+MODE?/AT+MODE[P1] - Query/Set Module Work Mode
>
> Mode 2: Before establishing a connection, you can use the AT command configuration
> module through UART. After established a connection, you can send data to remote side. Remote side
> can do fellows:
>
> - Send AT command configuration module
> - Remote control PIO2 to PIO11 pins output state of HM-10.
> - Remote control PIO2, PIO3 pins output state of HM-11.
> - Send data to module UART port (not include any AT command and per package
>   must less than 20 bytes).

I set mode 2 and write via Bluetooth in the characteristic 0xFFE1 - "AT\r\n (0x41,0x54,0x0d,0x0a)"

[image: characteristic ble module]

Why does the module send this AT command to the UART and not respond via Bluetooth?

UPDATE:

I am configuring via serial port by sending commands

1. AT+ROLE0 // set slave (response: OK+Set:0)
2. AT+MODE2 // set mode 2 (response: OK+Get:2)

AT+VERS? shows HMSoft V005

I send AT\r\n through Bluetooth just for test, through serial port the module responds OK to this command

Comment: Edit the question to include: What is the firmware version of your HM-10? why do you send this specific string/Hex: "AT\r\n (0x41,0x54,0x0d,0x0a)"? Where did you find the info about the work modes? (provide source/link/pdf). I suppose [this is your source](https://people.ece.cornell.edu/land/courses/ece4760/PIC32/uart/HM10/DSD%20TECH%20HM-10%20datasheet.pdf)? Also, provide details as to how you entered mode 2, you might made a mistake in entering mode 2.

Comment: @ChristianidisVasilis done

Comment: If you re-power/reset the BLE it returns to default mode (0) I believe. Do you connect via bluetooth after you enter MODE 2 or you re-power the HM-10 first? You might also need to firmware-update your HM-10 for the mode2 to function properly? Have you tried updating the firmware?